# Apache Flink: Cassandra Sink metrics

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I wrote a Flink app, using a Cassandra Sink. Everything works really well, but various metrics are not being generated (like Latency, NumRecordsInPerSecond, etc).

The following graphs are the only ones that show information.
[image]

I really need the latency metric Flink offers, but It doenst show any data.

Do I need to do something else to get the others graphs to work? Especially, the latency one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have not disabled LatencyMarker. By default, the LatencyMarker will be emitted every 2 seconds to calculate latency for each operator. You can set the interval to send LatencyMarker through `env.getConfig().setLatencyTrackingInterval(1000L);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfourtunately, the above code didn't work. I just noticed that not even sources (Kafka in my case) is also not registering latency.

Comment: Searching more of this issue, I found that the graph is currently not working, since [the value of the latency metric is not numeric](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Using-latency-markers-td14791.html)

Comment: @CamiloR Yeah, actually Flink provides latency metrics, but there is some wrong with the web ui to display to metric. You can get metric names for an operator through REST API: http://127.0.0.1:8081/jobs/[JOB-ID]/vertices/[VERTEX-ID]/metrics, and get latency through: http://127.0.0.1:8081/jobs/[JOB-ID]/vertices/[VERTEX-ID]/metrics?get=0.Map.latency. In my case, it returns: [{"id":"0.Map.latency","value":"{LatencySourceDescriptor{vertexID=17, subtaskIndex=-1}={p99=722.4499999999994, p50=147.5, min=29.0, max=750.0, p95=441.75, mean=183.3125}}"}]

Comment: That was the thing I was looking for! Their documentation on REST Monitoring API didn't mention it at all. Now that is something I can work with. Thanks you.